# Como puedo pasar data de mi page a otra page en ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

Necesito tomar el product.value de cada item, sumarlos, y pasarlo a otro componente.

Intente con navigate.params y no estoy encontrando la forma, muchas gracias por cualquier consejo o ayuda!

Mi product-list.html

```
<app-header titulo="Productos"></app-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar placeholder="Buscar turno disponible" (ionChange)="onSearch($event)" animated></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item lines="full" *ngFor="let product of products | filter: textoBuscar: 'description'"
      [routerLink]="['/product', product.id]">
      <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img src="../../../assets/gulf.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-label>{{ product.description }}</ion-label>
      <ion-label text-right>{{ product.stock }} litros</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Mi product-list.ts

```
export class ProductListPage implements OnInit {
  products: ProductI[];
  textoBuscar = ''
  productId: null;
  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadProducts();
  }
  async loadProducts() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Cargando'
    });
    await loading.present();
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
      loading.dismiss();
      this.products = res;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor forma de pasar valores entre componentes es usar un servicio que los almacene. En tu caso tienes el servicio ProductService, si le declaras una variable por ejemplo: sumatorio, puedes usarlo para almacenar la suma de los values y tenerla en el otro componente.

```
export class ProductService {
   private sumatorio:number;

   public setSumatorio(valor:number){
     this.sumatorio = valor;
   }
   public getSumatorio(){
     return this.sumatorio;
   }
...
```

Solo tienes que establecer el valor en el componente adecuado y obtenerlo en el otro:

```
export class ProductListPage implements OnInit {
  products: ProductI[];
  textoBuscar = ''
  productId: null;
  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadProducts();
  }
  async loadProducts() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Cargando'
    });
    await loading.present();
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
      loading.dismiss();
      this.products = res;
      let sumatorio:number=0
      this.products.forEach(product=>{
         sumatorio+=product.value;
      })
      this.productService.setSumatorio(sumatorio);
    });
  }

export class otroComponente implements OnInt {
   private sumatorio:number;
   constructor(
     private productService: ProductService,
     private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
   ) { }
   ngOnInit() {
     this.sumatorio = this.productService.getSumatorio();
   }
}
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien para mostrar el valor total! Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay de qué. Si te sirvió la respuesta márcala como correcta porfi ;)